# How to draw image on top of z-order of windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, draw

I trying to make ToolTip alike thing that popups an image when the mouse hovers some ToolStripButton.

I have the problem with displaying image... For some reason it draws under placed controls.

I tried to draw it that way:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e); //

        if (this.ToolTipImg != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.ToolTipImg, this.ToolTipTLP.X, this.ToolTipTLP.Y, this.ToolTipImg.Width, this.ToolTipImg.Height);

        //base.OnPaint(e); //and that too
    }

    //private void Form1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) //and here
    //{
        //if (this.ToolTipImg != null)
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.ToolTipImg, this.ToolTipTLP.X, this.ToolTipTLP.Y, this.ToolTipImg.Width, this.ToolTipImg.Height);
    //}
```

But the result is always same:

[image]

Comment: The form is always at the bottom of the Z-order, any child controls it has are always on top.  Which is why you can see them :)  You are using the wrong Paint event, you want the ToolStrip's.

Comment: Ugh, I though all controls simply renders in the form as image, so `base.OnPaint()` render all controls and then I paint over.

Comment: Actually, it's still good to know, how to draw on top of all, since it still draw under other controls

Comment: Real tooltips use a top-level window.  A form, basically.  Very unclear why you are trying to avoid using them, particularly since it is a built-in feature with the ToolTipText property.

Comment: @HansPassant - I tried to subscribe on ToolStrip's `Paint` event, but the image is still drawn under other controls and even under `ToolStripButtons`